# kernel version before installing it?

Tags: linux, redhat, kernel, up2date

I have redhat 4 with :

Actual kernel-----------------------> 2.6.9-78.0.17.ELsmp

new kernel available (up2date) --------> 2.6.9-89.x.xx.

For some reason , i need the new kernel version number before actually doing the upgrade...
Is there a safe way of doing this with up2date , without actualy doing the update.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3):

You could try with:

Output a list of packages available for updates, and all the dependencies they need, including obsoletes.

```
up2date --dry-run
```

Output a list of packages which have been updated and available for retrieval/installation.

```
up2date -l
```

Answer (score 1):

```
up2date --dry-run
```

will print out what needs to be updated..